# Inconsistent ETags in YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, etag

I'm looking at building a caching layer on top of the YouTube API and making use of the HTTP standard ETag functionality to do this as described here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags

I've done some direct testing of this against the API in most cases it seems to be working - I can get 304 responses etc.

However I'm seeing a few places where the API is returning different ETags when the response has not changed. 
In these cases the ETags seem to cycle between a set of values instead of being a single consistent value. 
When I pick one of the ETags and use it to send a conditional GET I will sometimes get a 304 back (when it matches) or sometimes get a 200 with a full response (when it was one of the other values) even though the actual response data is the same.

I've found this behaviour in at least two places:

1) youtube/v3/channels part=brandingSettings

In the response here the brandingSettings has a "hints" value which is an array of size 3. 
The order of the elements in this array is random and varies on each request however it seems to affect the etag, meaning I get 6 (permutations for 3 items) different possible ETags values for the same data.
Either the array order should be fixed or the ETag generation algorithm should account for this?

2) youtube/v3/channels part=contentDetails

The ETag for the response here seems to vary between 3 different values, despite there being no other differences in the data. In particular the other "etag" value within "items" remains constant.

Is this a bug in the YouTube API Etag implementation? Surely this behaviour will effectively break any caching layer trying to reduce data retrieval from the YouTube API?

Comment: Can you provide more information about this? Like what is the sample request that you are using.

Comment: The requests are 

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=ourkey&part=brandingSettings&id=UC2nZMhZ2qG5-xpqb440WLYg

and 

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=ourkey&part=contentDetails&id=UC2nZMhZ2qG5-xpqb440WLYg

The second one is now returning more than 3 different etags

Comment: @DavidGeary Did you solve this or understand why this is happening? I've been searching for a few hours and couldn't find a solution for this. I'm having the same issues when retrieving data from multiple videos and the ETag is randomly switching between few values.

Comment: @TheDrot Sorry didn't manage to find a solution for this. As it stands it seems to be a broken etag implementation.

Comment: @DavidGeary Well I noticed for [this](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=ourkey&part=brandingSettings&id=UC2nZMhZ2qG5-xpqb440WLYg) request, the item positions inside `brandingSettings => hints` subarray are displayed in random order and this is causing the etag to change. When those array positions stay the same, the etag also stays the same. There are 6 different possible positions and 6 different etags being returned.

Comment: @TheDrot Yes I mentioned that in the description above

Comment: Did anyone find a way to benefit from the current (buggy?) YT etag implementation?